# how to reverse an array in numpy fraction wise

Tags: arrays, numpy, reverse

I have a numpy array like :
[2,3,4,5]
and I want to make them inverse like:
[1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5]

I don't want to write it myself
is there any command?

Comment: Have you tried `1 / my_array`?

Comment: i tried numpy.power(num,(-1)) but it doesn't work

Comment: you answer worked
thank you

Comment: @NilsWernerNice could you please write it on answers section, then I can choose it as right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to write:

```
1 / my_array
```

Comment: Can you change this from a comment to an actual answer, at the moment this is a copy and paste of a comment